# Find what the conflicts were after a svn update

Tags: svn, conflict

After an update with thousands of lines of updated files and directory, I have one conflict:

```
Summary of conflicts:
  Skipped paths: 1
```

**Is there a way to find what the conflict was?** (A log somewhere or a svn option?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This special conflict message (Skipped paths) is created when the same file has been added to both the place your merging from as well as the place your merging to since the last merge.

```
svn status [PATH...]
```

**[svn status](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html)** (stat, st) prints the status of working copy files and directories

'**C**' :The contents (as opposed to the properties) of the item conflict with updates received from the repository.